# Eigen cannot add outer product to sparse row major matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, outer-product

The following code compiles without issues:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
int main(){
    typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat; 
    typedef Eigen::SparseVector<double> SpVec; 
    SpMat m (5,5);
    SpVec v (5);
    m+=v * v.transpose();
}
```

However, when I change

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;
```

to

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> SpMat;
```

I get an error message which includes

> /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseCwiseBinaryOp.h:48:13: error: static assertion failed: THE_STORAGE_ORDER_OF_BOTH_SIDES_MUST_MATCH

I tried changing the definition of SparseVector to make it Row/Column Major, but it did not seem to fix the issue. Does anybody know what should I do? I need to have RowMajor sparse matrix as I need quick access to rows.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended approach is, but since the outer product is symmetric, you can write `m += (v * v.transpose()).transpose()` which compiles. Also note that this operation has a specialized implementation known as [`rankUpdate`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseSelfAdjointView.html#a843bdc3844b4b9f5bc2daa84520d7bb7) like `m.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().rankUpdate(v)`. This would only update the lower triangle since the upper is redundant